# Evaluation of nullary functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

Suppose you have a nullary function in Haskell, which is used several times in the code. Is it always evaluated only once? I already tested the following code:

```
sayHello :: Int
sayHello = unsafePerformIO $ do
    putStr "Hello"
    return 42

test :: Int -> [Int]
test 0 = []
test n = (sayHello:(test (n-1)))
```

When I call `test 10`, it writes "Hello" only once, so it's indicating the result of function is stored after first evaluation. My question is, is it guaranteed? Will I get the same result across different compilers?

**Edit**
The reason I used `unsafePerformIO` is to check whether `sayHello` is evaluated more than once. I don't use that in my program. Normally I expect `sayHello` to have exactly the same result every time its evaluated. But it's a time-consuming operation, so I wanted to know if it could be accessed this way, or if it should be passed as an argument wherever it's needed to ensure it is not evaluated multiple times, i.e.:

```
test _ 0 = []
test s n = (s:(test (n-1)))
...
test sayHello 10
```

According to the answers this should be used.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no such thing as a nullary function. A function in Haskell has exactly one argument, and always has type `... -> ...`. `sayHello` is a value -- an `Int` -- but not a function. See [this article](http://conal.net/blog/posts/everything-is-a-function-in-haskell) for more.

On guarantees: No, you don't really get any guarantees. The Haskell report specifies that Haskell is non-strict -- so you know what value things will eventually reduce to -- but not any particular evaluation strategy. The evaluation strategy GHC generally uses is [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evalution), i.e. non-strict evaluation with sharing, but it doesn't make strong guarantees about that -- the optimizer could shuffle your code around so that things are evaluated more than once.

There are also various exceptions -- for example, `foo :: Num a => a` is polymorphic, so it probably won't be shared (it's compiled to an actual function). Sometimes a pure value might be evaluated by more than one thread at the same time (that won't happen in this case because `unsafePerformIO` explicitly uses `noDuplicate` to avoid it). So when you program, you can generally *expect* laziness, but if you want any sort of guarantees you'll have to be very careful. The Report itself won't really give you anything on *how* your program is evaluated.

`unsafePerformIO` gives you even less in the way of guarantees, of course. There's a reason it's called "unsafe".

Answer (score 5):

Top level no-argument functions like `sayHello` are called Constant Applicative Forms and are always memoised (atleast in GHC - see http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/profiling.html). You would have to resort to tricks like passing in dummy arguments and turning optimisations off to *not* share a CAF globally.

*Edit*: quote from the link above -

> Haskell is a lazy language, and certain expressions are only ever
>   evaluated once. For example, if we write:
>   `x = nfib 25` then `x` will only be evaluated once (if at all), and
>   subsequent demands for `x` will immediately get to see the cached result.
>   The definition `x` is called a CAF (Constant Applicative Form), because
>   it has no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If you do want "Hello" printed n times, you need to remove the `unsafePermformIO`, so the runtime will know it can't optimize away repeated calls to `putStr`. I'm not clear whether you want to return the list of int, so I've written two versions of test, one of which returns (), one [Int].

```
sayHello2 :: IO Int
sayHello2 = do
    putStr "Hello"
    return 42

test2 :: Int -> IO ()
test2 0 = return ()
test2  n = do
  sayHello2
  test2 (n-1)

test3 :: Int -> IO [Int]
test3 0 = return []
test3 n = do
  r <- sayHello2
  l <- test3 (n-1)
  return $ r:l
```